# What happened to the Delphi Decision Support Components?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4 Enterprise and I don't see any [Decision Support Components](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/14adeccoverviewofdecisionsupportcomponents_xml.html) such as:

- [TDecisionCube](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXDB_TDecisionCube.html)
- [TDecisionSource](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXDB_TDecisionSource.html)
- [TDecisionQuery](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXTABLES_TDecisionQuery.html)
- [TDecisionPivot](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXPIVSRC_TDecisionPivot.html)
- [TDecisionGrid](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXGRID_TDecisionGrid.html)
- [TDecisionGraph](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/MXGRAPH_TDecisionGraph.html)

According to page 22-2 of the [Delphi 7 Developer Guide](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphi7/D7_DevelopersGuide.pdf):
"The decision support components appear on the Decision Cube page of the
Component palette."

There is no Decision Cube Page on the Component pallet of my version of XE4 Enterprise.

Do these components still exist?

Comment: IIRC, they were an option in the installer (at least in D2010). I don't have it here at home; I may have installed it at the office.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Decision Cube stuff was added during the first attempt to create a high end SKU for Delphi.  The DocWiki still contains a vague reference to the TDecisionCube, but the last version I remember seeing it in was Delphi 2007. At that point it was already deprecated. Wasn't it BDE-only?

Comment: @WarrenP: A later version (Professional SKU) added the source as an option to the installation. I'm pretty sure I have it on a machine at the office - I looked at the source and it was pretty nasty, and it may depend on the BDE. Ah, that may be why it's not installed by default any longer! (And why I don't have it anywhere here - I never install the BDE, but I may have a remnant at the office.)

Comment: Gunny (Mike): If you can't find it, it may be because it's part of the deprecated BDE stuff now. When D7 was current, the BDE was still around; it was deprecated a little later, and hasn't been supported or updated in at least a decade now.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm finally reading Part II of the Delphi 7 Developer Guide and it references these components. If it is BDE then I'm not really interested. ;-)

Comment: Got it. Making the most of that couple of reams of paper? :-) I'm pretty sure it was based on the BDE; I think the reason I remember them releasing the source is that I'd forgotten to uncheck the BDE during an install, and ran across it before I realized the mistake and reran the install to remove the BDE again.

Comment: Maybe helpful: 

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27848

Comment: @Warren - Thanks for the article link... too bad it doesn't have a date written. IIRC most of those article do not have a date written. :(

Comment: I added some Delphi 2007 documentation references. These components were tremendously useful in presenting OLAP style information. It is too bad they were never updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just checked.

Up until Delphi XE3, the `MX*.pas` sources for Decision Cube were in the `...\source\xtab` directory.

These units do not depend on BDE:

- Mxarrays
- Mxconsts
- MXDCONST
- MXPBAR

These units depend on the BDE:

- MXBUTTON
- MXCOMMON
- MXDB
- MXDCUBE
- MXDIMEDT
- MXDSQL
- MXDSSQRY
- MXGRAPH
- MXGRID
- MXPIVSRC
- MXQEDCOM
- MXQPARSE
- MXTABLES
- MXREG
- Mxstore

Note of the above sources have changed since 1999.

The odd thing: `DBTABLES.PAS` (for the BDE `TTable` / `TQuery` components) still ships with Delphi XE4.